# Moodle gives "Session handler is misconfigured" error after migration

Tags: php, mysql, linux, moodle

I migrated a website that uses moodle. Now I get this error: `"Session handler is misconfigured"`.

I've checked the server for logs, but I couldn't find anything and I've checked all files permission:

*php -v*

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57)
```

*mysql -V*

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

Any ideea how to solve this kind of issues?

Comment: Switch on developer debugging and then include the stack trace in the question - add these to `config.php` `$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT; // 32767; $CFG->debugdisplay = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing memcache module, memcache was the most used cache engine.
Simply (in ubuntu) install in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcached memcached
```

You also have to start memcached and restart apache2 in this way:

```
service memcached start
service apache2 restart
```